# COM object used for long time

Tags: c#, com, opc

how to used the COM object for the lifetime in C#

I will be created the OPC server object, it will be used into the threading.timer this timer will be invoked at every seconds after the some time opcserver object, it will be release itself shoe the exception as "  COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.."

Here is the code

```
public partial class OPC_server : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
{
    private System.Threading.Timer timer1;
    private System.Threading.Timer timer2;
    parameter param = new parameter();//another class
    private static readonly object myLockHolder = new object();
    private static readonly object myLockHolder1 = new object();
    public static OpcServer[] _opcServer;

    private void OPC_server_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getconnectedOPC();
    }

    public void getconnectedOPC()
    {
        ds = opcconn.GetOPCServerInfo();
        int i=0;
        DataTable dtOPC=new DataTable();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0 || ds.Tables[0] != null)
        {
            dtOPC = ds.Tables[0].Copy();
            _opcServer = new OpcServer[dtOPC.Rows.Count];
            TimeSpan delayTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            TimeSpan intervalTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 450);
            foreach (DataRow row in dtOPC.Rows)
            {
                if (i <= dtOPC.Rows.Count)
                {
                    //connetion(row);
                    getconnect(i, row, dtOPC.Rows.Count);
                    i++;
                }

            }
            connetion(dtOPC.Rows.Count);
        }
    }

    //connecting the server 
    public void getconnect(int conn, DataRow r,int rows)
    {

        DataSet ds2=new DataSet();
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        try
        {

            string machinename = Convert.ToString(r["OPCIPAddress"]);
            string servername = Convert.ToString(r["OPCName"]);

            _opcServer[conn] = new OpcServer();
            int i = _opcServer[conn].Connect(machinename, servername);
            if (i == 0)
            {
                opcconn.update("true", servername);
                writelog(servername, "connected");
            }

            else
            {
                opcconn.update("false", servername);
                writelog(servername, "disconnected");
            }
        }
        catch (OPCException e)
        {
            servername = Convert.ToString(r["OPCName"]);
            opcconn.update("false", servername);
            writelog(servername, e.Message.ToString());
        }
        catch (ApplicationException e)
        {
            servername = Convert.ToString(r["OPCName"]);
            opcconn.update("false", servername);
            writelog(servername, "No instance server");
        }  
   }


    public void OPCthread(DataRow r2,int timerinfo)
    {
    if (timerinfo == 0)
    {
       int rer = Convert.ToInt32(r2["refreshRate"]);//at least 1 second
       TimeSpan dueTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0,0,0,rer);
      TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0 ,0 ,rer);
       timer1 = new System.Threading.Timer(register, r2, dueTime,interval);
            }
    else if (timerinfo == 1)
    {

        TimeSpan dueTime;
        TimeSpan interval;
        int rer1 = Convert.ToInt32(r2["refreshRate"]);
        dueTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, rer1);
        interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, rer1);
        timer2 = new System.Threading.Timer(register1, r2, dueTime, interval);
    }
}

public void register(object row1)
{
    try
    {
        lock (myLockHolder)
        {
            int cnt = 0, cnt1 = 0;
            ItemValue[] rVals;
            OPCItemDef[] item;
            OpcServer srv = new OpcServer();
            string[] array;
            //SrvStatus status1;
            DataSet paramds = new DataSet();
            DataTable paramdt = new DataTable();
            DataRow dt = (System.Data.DataRow)row1;
            int serverID = Convert.ToInt32(dt["OPCServerID"]);
           paramds = param.getparameter(Convert.ToInt32(dt["groupID"]));

            if (Convert.ToBoolean(dt["setactive"]) == true)
            {
          if (paramds != null && paramds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    paramdt = paramds.Tables[0].Copy();
                    int tq = 0;
                    item = new OPCItemDef[paramdt.Rows.Count];
                    int clienthandle = 1;
                    foreach (DataRow r in paramdt.Rows)
                    {
                        if (tq < item.Length)
                        {
              item[tq] = new OPCItemDef(Convert.ToString(r["param_ID"]), Convert.ToBoolean(r["active"]), clienthandle, VarEnum.VT_EMPTY);
                            ++clienthandle;
                            tq++;
                        }

                    }
                    array = new string[item.Length];
                    cnt1 = 0;
                    while (cnt1 < array.Length)
                    {
                        array[cnt1] = item[cnt1].ItemID;
                        cnt1++;
                    }
          rVals = _opcServer[serverID - 1].Read(array, Convert.ToInt32(dt["refreshRate"]));
              param.update(rVals, Convert.ToInt32(dt["groupID"]));
                }
            }
        }

    }

    catch (ThreadAbortException) { }
    finally {  }
}

public void register1(object row2)
{
    try
    {
        lock (myLockHolder1)
        {
            int cnt = 0, cnt11 = 0;
            ItemValue[] rVals1;
            OPCItemDef[] item1;
            OpcServer srv1 = new OpcServer();
            string[] array1;
            DataSet paramds1 = new DataSet();
            DataTable paramdt1 = new DataTable();
            DataRow dt1 = (System.Data.DataRow)row2;
            int serverID1 = Convert.ToInt32(dt1["OPCServerID"]);
            //  Boolean gstatus = grpclass.getstatus(Convert.ToInt32(dt["groupID"]));
            paramds1 = param.getparameter2(Convert.ToInt32(dt1["groupID"]));
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(dt1["setactive"]) == true)
            {
                if (paramds1 != null)
                {
                    paramdt1 = paramds1.Tables[0].Copy();
                    int tq1 = 0;
                    item1 = new OPCItemDef[paramdt1.Rows.Count];
                    int clienthandle1 = 1;
                    foreach (DataRow r in paramdt1.Rows)
                    {
                        if (tq1 < item1.Length)
                        {
                            item1[tq1] = new OPCItemDef(Convert.ToString(r["param_ID"]), Convert.ToBoolean(r["active"]), clienthandle1, VarEnum.VT_EMPTY);
                            clienthandle1++;
                            tq1++;
                        }

                    }
                    array1 = new string[item1.Length];
                    cnt11 = 0;
                    while (cnt11 < array1.Length)
                    {
                        array1[cnt11] = item1[cnt11].ItemID;
                        cnt11++;
                    }
       rvals = _opcServer[serverID1 - 1].Read(array1, Convert.ToInt32(dt1["refreshRate"]));
                    param.update1(rVals1, Convert.ToInt32(dt1["groupID"]));
                }

            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
    finally { }
}
```

please tell me the proper solution

Comment: You have posted a massive amount of code, but your problem and question are unclear. Can you simplify this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [COM Object used for lifetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754389/com-object-used-for-lifetime)

Answer (score 0):

When you are using OPC, you are using COM.  Since you are also using a GUI, you are most likely using Single-Threaded Apartment (STA) for your `ApartmentState`.  When this is the case, you should make sure that the OPC calls all happen on the thread that first instantiates the OPC object.  Since the COM object is created on an STA thread, then it will try to marshal all the calls back onto that thread.

To make this work, you'll need to use a separate `Thread` instead of a `System.Threading.Timer` to do the OPC calls so that they are always on the same thread.  The `System.Threading.Timer` callback will execute on a different thread (from the thread pool) every time (non-deterministic).  You'll get better performance keeping it off the UI thread too, if the server is not responding, you'll get lack in the UI.  Also, the server has the option of closing connections on a whim if it wants.  You'll get an OPC Shutdown event that will tell you the server wants you to disconnect.